# Nothing that happens to Messenger bot should be sent as an event to my terminal where the webhook is running

Tags: python, python-3.x, facebook, facebook-graph-api, chatbot

I want to build a bot on messenger with Python. I am following the [official documentation from Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/getting-started/sample-apps/original-coast-clothing), but they are using a repository made in javascript, and [this Youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IEyEOZ1C5VM&list=PLzYhaL0-zg4V_4EMv_BYHHENjYdJhbEQm&index=3) which is in python but already one year old, so not up to date.

When sending a message to the app I don't get any data back despite running the following code, which I believe is a webhook:

```
from flask import Flask, request

PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN = 'My Page Access Tokens from https://developers.facebook.com/apps/2924966724200691/messenger/settings/'

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET'])
def webhook():
    if request.method =='GET':
        token = request.args.get('hub.verify_token')
        challenge = request.args.get('hub.challenge')
        if token == 'secret':
            return str(challenge)
        return '400'

    else:
        print(request.data)
        return '200'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

I am using ngrok. 
Everything that happens to Messenger bot should be sent as an event to my terminal where the webhook is running. Yet I don't have anythong. Let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: Are you running this on your local computer?  It's highly likely you do not have a publicly addressable ip and therefor Facebook can't reach your `Flask` app.

Comment: @JBirdVegas they said they are using ngrok, so in that regard it’s probably fine.

Comment: Did you successfully go through all the steps, including the verification part? Did you successfully subscribe to any relevant webhooks events? Are you using this with users with a role in the app (as long as the app is in dev mode and not reviewed yet)?